# VBA checking multiple html checkboxes on web

Tags: html, excel, vba, forms, web-scraping

The goal is to check multiple checkboxes depends on data in cell J(i) that is seperated with delimiter "|".

> Example: Column J, Row (i) = SkillA|SkillB|SkillC

Checkbox: check/click this 3 skills.

At the moment I am able to select only 1 checkbox by storing only 1 id in cell J:

> Cell J = SkillA

```
Doc.getElementById(sht.Range("J" & i)).Click
```

Full code:

```
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fields")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    '--------------------------------
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate sht.Range("A" & i).Value
    Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    Set Doc = IE.document
code....
code....
     Doc.getElementById("tab6").Click
     Doc.getElementById(sht.Range("J" & i)).Click

    Next i
    IE.Quit
    MsgBox "Process 100% completed"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little confusing but sounds like you want to use split to generate an array of values you can pass as id values for checkboxes

```
Dim values() As String, i As Long
values = Split(sht.Range("J" & i).Value, "|")

For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    On Error Resume Next
    Doc.getElementById(values(i)).Click
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

Comment: 1 thing is still not exactly as I wanted to - I would like to use the values as names (SkillA|SkillB|SkillC etc) but at the moemnet only Id works (ID1|ID2|ID3). Here an example of the element: <input name="role" id="chkID1" onclick="somethinghappens" type="checkbox" features="ACM|">
<label id="lblID1" for="chkID1">SkillA</label>

Comment: You are using getElementById so only valid ids will work. If you want a method to use to select by name attribute this will in part depend on how many with any given name you have? Is there only ever one attribute on the page with a given name?

Comment: There are 337 unique ID with Unique names per ID, In the future might be 500 & 1000 id's / names.

Comment: And you want to select a checkbox based on name? Doc.querySelector("[name='yourNameValueGoesHere']").click    .Try that. If doesn't work please post a new question and I will have a look at it there.

Comment: Yes, after the elemnt "for="chkID1" the is a name > SkillA </label>. How do I make it take "SkillA" instead of the "chkID1"? idialy SkillA|SkillB|SkillC will be stored in column J

Comment: ? I don't understand. The SkillA there is an innerText value. It is assigned by  .value = ""     .getElementById("chkID1").value = "SkillA"

Comment: I am not sure how to call the element that store the name SkillA, as in other cases I could clearly see ID element and Name element, while in this html code the name SkillA seems like not connected to anything. Would it be easier if I edit(if possible) the first comment and try to better describe my difficlty? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: htmldoc.querySelector("[for='chkID1']").click

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question and showing the relevant HTML if the above doesn't work.